# What would my over subscription be for my network?

Tags: networking, cisco, switch, datacenter, rack

I have 24 racks with 20 servers each connecting to 2 by 48 x 10G switches in each rack (NIC teaming). The switchs then connects to another 2 by 48 x 10G switches in 2 aggregation racks.

What would the oversubscription ratio be? Or how would I determine this? Is there anything else I need to consider for this?

Comment: How are the switches in the server racks connected to the aggregating switches?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on which link you're talking about, and what you mean by 'NIC teaming'.  Assuming it's active/standby...

- 20 servers @ 10Gbps into switch with 10Gbps ports = 1:1 for your local switch (assuming backplane itself is not oversubscribed)
- 200Gbps of servers aggregated into 1 (?) 10Gbps port towards the aggregation switch = 20:1 for the ToR switch to the aggregation layer

Why is the specific "oversubscription" ratio important to you?  To effectively design for a setup like this, you'd need to know average throughput, traffic characteristics, destinations (intra-switch vs inter-switch), etc.  A server with a 10Gbps link that only does minor DNS requests is a much different traffic consideration than a fileserver or a DB server.   What are you trying to accomplish by determining these numbers in particular?